# Autocomplete="off" selector

Tags: jquery

How to target the HTML elements that has Autocomplete off?

I have the following HTML:

```
<input id="Password" name="Password" type="password" autocomplete="off">
```

And I am using the following:

```
$('input[type="password"]').val('');
```

But instead of targeting all inputs of type password I would like to target all elements that have autocomplete="off".

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried `$('input[autocomplete="off"]')`?

Comment: In a way, You have answered your answer.

Comment: A quick google wouldn't hurt - googling for "jquery select by attribute" comes up with the link ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an attribute selector:

`$("input[autocomplete='off']")`

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Auto complete is an attribute like any other. Just use the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

```
$('input[autocomplete="off"]')
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t1jof6tf/) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

This is done using jQueries [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

You can select elements like: `#('.class[attr="value"]')`. In your case this would be `$('input[autocomplete="off"]')` to select all the elements that don't have autocomplete.

Credits to @alan0xd7 for beating me here ;P